# Tried to do a BCC transaction ended in a BTC transaction

Tags: ecash

I have a local BTC wallet. Which holds coins from pre-fork times.

So I tried to get my BCC amount sent to a wallet on bitfinex. So I used my local wallet with the BitcoinABC client to access the BCCs.

But that ended up in sending my BTCs to this address. The address indeed exists as BTC as well, so the transaction was successful. But i don't even have access to this BTC wallet (only the BCC wallet).

Why did the BitcoinABC client sent my BTCs (which are much higher in value...)? It says BCC everywhere. I was not even aware, that Bitcoin ABC is capable of performing BTC transactions. What did I do wrong?

Comment: What version of Bitcoin ABC are you using?  I am not sure, but this might happen if you used an old version from before replay protection was implemented.  Otherwise, this isn't supposed to be possible.  Would you be willing to share the transaction ID?

Comment: Version is v0.14.6.0-a46e63c.
Transaction is this: https://blockchair.com/search?q=f343a0cb812fb05839d8e1f044d04db0b4210b7931e3a19628c369a2f4430479